# How to scrape page headers (ie: html_nodes("h1")) from a list of html files using rvest?

Tags: html, r, for-loop, if-statement, rvest

The end goal of this question is to create a data frame of URLs in one column, and the header of that page in another. I'll explain my approach -- but feel free to explain it by using a list of websites instead of html files.

The reason for creating a list of html files is that some of the URLs produce an error when scraping using read_html directly on the list of websites. The try function gets around that.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(uniques)) { 
    try(download.file(uniques$URL.Found.On[i], 
    destfile = paste("scrapedpage", i, "html", sep = "."), quiet=TRUE)) 
        }
```

This produces a list of 11k websites. However, perhaps because I used the try function, it created some html files that this next function won't read.

```
content <- NULL    
for (i in 1:nrow(uniques)) { 
    content[i] <- read_html(paste("scrapedpage", i, "html", sep = ".")) %>% 
    html_nodes("h1") %>% html_text()
    }
```

This works for the first three items of my list, so I know I'm on the right track, but it doesn't go through the entire list. I get the following message:

> Error in content[i] <- read_html(paste("scrapedpage", i, "html", sep = ".")) %>%  : 
>     replacement has length zero

Could it be that the 4th html file from this list has no "h1" header, or some other factor that limits the usefulness of this function?

Is there a way to just leave an NA if no "h1" is found, so that it doesn't break the for loop? Maybe adding in an ifelse statement? Any ideas are appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your `read_html(paste("scrapedpage", i, "html", sep = ".")) %>% 
html_nodes("h1") %>% html_text()` block work correctly for a single file?

Comment: Also, I wouldn't use `nrow(uniques)` for your second loop index. I'd recommend `for (i in list.files(pattern=('.*\\.html$")))` because `nrow(uniques)` may not equal the number of scrapped pages.

Comment: Also, `content` needs to be initialized `content <- list()`

Comment: Hi Mako. Yes I initialized the content variable, but forgot to mention that in post. Good catch.

As for the question about uniques being equal to the value of the scraped pages -- they are indeed. I have the folder of html files to prove that.

For the question of the block working on a single file, it does for many of the html files in my folder, but not on all of them. Examples of output on individual sites include: "Institutional Review Board for Social Behavioral Sciences, U.Va." and "Additional Teacher Preparation Resources"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping it in a `tryCatch` block, if some of the files are failing, this should catch it and print your errors, while letting the code finish:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(uniques)) {
    tryCatch({ 
      content[i] <- read_html(paste("scrapedpage", i, "html", sep = ".")) %>% 
      html_nodes("h1") %>% html_text()
     }, error = function(e) print(sprintf("Error in: %i %s", i, as.character(e)))
    )
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that you were right that the original download file function produced 10,778 items out of a possible 11,075 -- possibly meaning there could be server problems with some of the websites. It would be useful to know a function to quickly identify which ones those are.

Comment: Assuming when a download fails it throws an error, you can replace your `try` in the first statement with another `tryCatch` block, which will then return a list of fails, similar to how my answer does for the second part. You could change the code after `function(e)` to write out to a file, instead of logging to the console too.